# Distinguishing a multi-select field in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

We are using the `_apis/wit/workitemtypes/{workitemtype}/fields?$expand=all&api-version=5.1` API to fetch all fields for a particular workitem type and then use the `_apis/wit/fields/{fieldreferencename}?api-version=5.1` API to fetch extra details about each field.

With the output we receive we're able to distinguish number, text, single-select fields.

However multi-select fields have no attribute that helps us identify them as multi-select fields.  Is there any other API for that? Another problem we have is that we're not able to distinguish custom fields from fields fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However multi-select fields have no attribute that helps us identify
>   them as multi-select fields.

I'm afraid this is not supported in current Rest-API [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/fields?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1). For now Rest-API doesn't support to check whether a field is multi-select.

> Is there any other API for that? Another problem we have is that we're
>   not able to distinguish custom fields from fields fields.

I think the api(`_apis/wit/fields/{fieldreferencename}?api-version=5.1`) in your question can handle this. For those custom fields, their referenceName is always in format: `Custom.FieldName`. See:

[image]

So to determine if one field is custom one, we just need to check its referenceName's format. Hope it helps and if I misunderstand anything, feel free to correct me.